# Adding and reading integers to RandomAcessFile from a List. All except the last one seem to be "0"

Tags: java, seek, randomaccessfile

I'm trying to write five random numbers from a List to a file.
I think I'm managing to write something but when I try to read the file they are all `0` except the last one.
I've searched but most of what I've found just explain how to write one int/string.
I think the problem comes from how I am writing. `writeInt` writes as four bytes and maybe I'm not using `seek()` in accordance.

This is my code.

```
try {
        RandomAccessFile ficheroJugador1 = new RandomAccessFile("jugador1.dat", "rw");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                ficheroJugador1.seek(i);
                int numEscribir = jugador1.numerosAleatorios.get(i);
                ficheroJugador1.writeInt(numEscribir);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                ficheroJugador1.seek(i);
                try {
                    System.out.println(ficheroJugador1.readInt());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        try {
            ficheroJugador1.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This results in:

> Numbers [10, 9, 3, 8, 7] //The numbers I want to write and read
>
> 0
>
> 0
>
> 0
>
> 0
>
> 7

Comment: Just an advice for life: Code in english. Why? Because everybody does. Writing code in english will help you to understand other people's code, and will help other people to understand your code. It's a win win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, by not using seek correctly you are overwriting the last saved number

```
(ascii representation)
0010
^
00009
 ^
000003
  ^
000008
   ^
00000007
    ^
```

If you change `ficheroJugador1.seek(i);` to `ficheroJugador1.seek(i*4);` you will correctly give each number its space

```
(ascii representation)
00100009000300080007
```